# Triggering events in actionscript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm working on a banner ad using based on a computer keyboard in flash. I am using pre-made keyboard code (bought from activeden) written in AS2. It has a function that riggers an animation when you rollover the movie clip.

I want to know how to trigger the rollover event on that movie clip without having to rewrite anything too much. something along the lines of `_root.button1.rollover()` would be fantastic (I come from a javascript background so please correct me if this is incorrect syntax).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can find the absolute path to the clip by putting

```
trace(this)
```

on the first frame in the clip you want to access. Then in your output window you will see the correct path to this clip. Once you have the path you need to use the correct function name to make this work. Most likely this will be `onMouseOver();`